# Odoo new Api change onchange field.Selection

Tags: api, orm, model, odoo

How can I cumpute field.Selection???

```
listing_type = fields.Selection(string="Format", selection=[('Chinese', 'Auction'),
                                                            ('FixedPriceItem', 'Fixed Price')], required=True)
listing_duration = fields.Selection([
    ('Days_1', '1 days'),
    ('Days_3', '3 days'),
    ('Days_5', '5 days'),
    ('Days_7', '7 days'),
    ('Days_10', '10 days'),
    ('Days_30', '30 days'),
    ('GTC', 'GTC'),
], string="Duration", required=True, compute='_return_listing_duration')


@api.one
@api.depends('listing_type')
def _return_listing_duration(self):
    if not self.listing_type:
        return
    if self.listing_type == 'Chinese':
        self.listing_duration.selection = [
            ('Days_1', '1 days'),
            ('Days_3', '3 days'),
            ('Days_5', '5 days'),
            ('Days_7', '7 days'),
            ('Days_10', '10 days')
        ]
    elif self.listing_type == 'FixedPriceItem':
        self.listing_duration.selection = [
            ('Days_3', '3 days'),
            ('Days_5', '5 days'),
            ('Days_7', '7 days'),
            ('Days_10', '10 days'),
            ('Days_30', '30 days'),
            ('GTC', 'GTC')
        ]
```

My method _return_listing_duration unfortunately not working.
_return_listing_duration()
-> ('Days_10', '10 days')

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('listing_type')
def _return_listing_duration(self):
    if not self.listing_type:
        return
    if self.listing_type == 'Chinese':
        self.listing_duration = [
            ('Days_1', '1 days'),
            ('Days_3', '3 days'),
            ('Days_5', '5 days'),
            ('Days_7', '7 days'),
            ('Days_10', '10 days')
        ]
    elif self.listing_type == 'FixedPriceItem':
        self.listing_duration = [
            ('Days_3', '3 days'),
            ('Days_5', '5 days'),
            ('Days_7', '7 days'),
            ('Days_10', '10 days'),
            ('Days_30', '30 days'),
            ('GTC', 'GTC')
        ]
```

Comment: computed fields.Selection seems not possible. I not found any solution to change the selection depending on other field.